# Finding Duplicate record on phpmyadmin Server type: MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table of students and I wish to display a list of all occurances where:

- A student's name is shared with at least one other student
- The frequency of each duplication

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    name 
    , COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM 
    student 
GROUP BY 
    name 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

My results are as follows:

```
1054 - Unknown column 'gt' in 'having clause'
```

Has anyone else experienced this error?

I don't understand it.

Comment: It looks like you're typing the query into a badly written HTTP application. Nothing wrong with your query. Nothing wrong with the database. Since you didn't tell us anything about the database client application, we can't help you.

Comment: @symcbean I am using this query on phpmyadmin and server type MariaDB

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: Query needs to be `SELECT name , count(*) as CNT from student GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` with the star in the count() function

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins unfortunately Sowndarya corrected the ops issue his/her edit making this post meaningless.. Original post had count() in both cases.

Comment: @RaymondNijland using the same query but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of HAVING.
I always do something like

```
SELECT x.* FROM
{
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS n
GROUP BY name
} x
WHERE x.n > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an editing problem.  What the heck are you using to type your SQL?

The "htmlentity" for `>` is `&gt;`.  Fix that character; the gt will work, and the `HAVING` will work.  (And it work faster thn using a subquery.)